# MySQL broken, databases deleted

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL 5.6. One time my server was suddenly stopped. MySQL is not starting now. In the folder where databases folders and files was stored - all folders was disappeared and only folder "WARNINGS" is there. When I try to start mysql I am getting the next log:

```
2018-09-21 03:02:31 0 [Note] c:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6-x64\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.6.38) starting as process 4600 ...
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
c:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6-x64\bin\mysqld.exe: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 633063664 and 633063664 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 633063674 in the ib_logfiles!
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2018-09-21 03:02:31 4600 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2018-09-21 03:02:32 4600 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-09-21 03:02:32 4600 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-09-21 03:02:32 4600 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.38 started; log sequence number 633063674
2018-09-21 03:02:32 4600 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
2018-09-21 03:02:32 4600 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2018-09-21 03:02:32 4600 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2018-09-21 03:02:32 4600 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

I have been trying mysql_upgrade, mysqld --initialize-insecure it doesn't help me.

My script feature is it running 16 threads 24 hours per day without stopping. So 16 connections are connected to DB everytime. 
On mysql configuration I have set:

```
interactive_timeout=31536000
wait_timeout=2147483
```

And nothing more unusual.

I have this situation second time, when the DB was broken.
I want to know, why do I get this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: I would check SMART of the hard drive where MySQL was located. Usually such restore problems arise from hardware fault

Comment: Does it mean the problem has technical character ? I mean problem with "iron") I thought it is just hard load on DB

Comment: You need to exclude possible hardware problems first. When files start disappear from disc it can be hardware problem and as you mentioned your script generated 24h load on file system and disc